# How to avoid the `\lstset{language=⟨language⟩,...}` before each `lstlisting` when code blocks are exported from org-mode to LaTeX?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

With `(setq org-latex-listings t)`, code blocks are exported from `org-mode` to `LaTeX` into:

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

So far, so good. But is there a way to avoid the `\lstset{language=⟨language⟩,label= ,caption= ,captionpos=b,numbers=none}` systematically added before each of the `lstlisting` LaTeX environments.

Here is an example:

```
#+OPTIONS:   toc:nil title:nil

#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{xcolor}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{listings}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \lstset{language=[auto]lisp,basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\color{red}}

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports code
  (defun org-xor (a b)
    "Exclusive or."
    (if a (not b) b))
#+END_SRC
```

which is exported into (only the relevant parts are shown):

```latex
...
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[auto]lisp,basicstyle=\ttfamily,keywordstyle=\color{red}}
...
\lstset{language=Lisp,label= ,caption= ,captionpos=b,numbers=none}
\begin{lstlisting}
(defun org-xor (a b)
  "Exclusive or."
  (if a (not b) b))
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might think it's unnecessary, but if you name your code block (e.g. so that you can provide a link to it through `hyperref`) or you provide a caption for it or you ask that its lines be numbered, then it's necessary. Try this code block and see:

```org
#+NAME: foo
#+CAPTION: my code block
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp -n :exports code
  (defun org-xor (a b)
    "Exclusive or."
    (if a (not b) b))
#+END_SRC
```

So my advice is to leave it alone and not worry about it. It does not hurt anything if you don't use the extra facilities: the only thing it does is add some clutter to the TeX file - but that's why we write in Org mode, right? The only time I look at the resulting TeX file is when I need to debug something - and yes, it'd be nice if there was no clutter then, but then the `ox-latex` code would need to be much more complicated: having some clutter in an unseen corner is a trade-off that's well worth making.

Comment: In my (rather complex) use case that I will explain if needed, it hurts :) But also in the MCE above since it overrides the `language=[auto]lisp` global setting and, then, the `if` keyword isn't highlighted anymore.

Comment: I don't know what `[auto]` does (I use `minted`, not `listings`) and why `listings` does not highlight the `if` in that case, but if this is the only reason, then it would seem better to me to change the transcoder of source blocks to include it with the language. The trouble is that it has to work for all languages: does `[auto]python` etc work in `listings`? BTW, the inline source code transcoder is the function `org-latex-inline-src-block` in `ox-latex.el` if you want to take a look.

Comment: No, `[auto]python` doesn't work in `listings`. As shown page 13 of the `listings` documentation, the point is that not only (main) languages are known, but also dialects. In my use case, I define several dialects of a given language (namely `TeX`) and that I load them with the global setting `\lstset{alsolanguage=..., alsolanguage=..., alsolanguage=..., ...}`. The systematic `\lstset{language=LaTeX,...}` inserted during the export override this global setting.

Comment: About `org-latex-inline-src-block`, I see only things such as `\\lstinline[%s]` and nothing about `\lstset{language=⟨language⟩,label= ,caption= ,captionpos=b,numbers=none}`. Is it the right function?

Comment: No, sorry (I was thinking of the inline block in your other question): the correct function is `org-latex-src-block`.

Comment: Commenting `"\\lstset{%s}\n"` line 3053 of this file doesn't change anything. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to comment out the whole `(format  "\\lstset{%s}\n" ...)` form. In my version, those are lines 3109-3131 in `ox-latex.el` ending with `...        (and local-options (concat "," local-options)))))` - in your version, presumably they will be lines 3052-3074 or thereabouts. And you will need to re-evaluate the function with `C-M-x` to activate the modified definition.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! How could I prevent this setting to be overridden by a future update of `org-mode`? Currently, my version is 9.4.4: is yours more up to date?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134449/discussion-between-nickd-and-denis-bitouze).